# Loopback - How to access custom method with related model?

Tags: loopbackjs

First please apologize my english.

I'm trying to access a custom remote method of one of my model with a related model.

I've created 3 models in Loopback which are related this way:

`User hasMany Shop` & `Shop belongTo User`

`Shop hasMany Credit` & `Credit belongTo Shop`

`User.nestRemoting("shops")` for `User` to reach `Credit` through `Shop`, `User` being the main entry point for the API.

`Credit` can be bought by a `User` for a `Shop` to execute some actions which cost `Credit`.

I've also created a custom remote method for `Credit`: `availableCredit(shopId)` which sum the `Credit` being available (those bought by `User` for a `Shop`and those spent by a `User` for a `Shop`).

I've registered my custom method in `credit.json` and it went fine.

```
"methods": {
    "availableCredits": {
      "description": Returns the available credits for the shop",
      "accessType": "READ",
      "shared": true,
      "http": {
        "path": "/available",
        "verb": "get",
        "status": 200
      },
      "accepts": [
        {
          "arg": "shopId",
          "type": "string",
          "description": "shop id",
          "required": true
        }
      ],
      "returns": {
        "arg": "credits",
        "type": "number"
      }
    }
  }
```

Everything works BUT my custom method DOESN'T show on API Loopback Explorer under `shops` or `user`.

I do see and have access to all the build-in methods like (in user):

```
GET /users/{id}/shops/{nk}/credits
```

Or my custom method in credit:

```
GET /credits/available
```

but I DON'T have

```
GET /users/{id}/shops/{nk}/credits/available
```

nor

```
GET /shops/{id}/credits/available
```

Does anyone knows if it's possible and has any idea of how it works ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like there's an issue open for this: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/1865

My guess is that the issue will either be in how [strong-remoting](https://github.com/strongloop/strong-remoting) does the routing, or how [loopback](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback) creates the remote method on the model.

I haven't had the best experience with strongloop when trying to get issues resolved or PR's merged. Good luck!

Comment: Haven't you resisted your custom method under user.js ? I think this issue might be resolve by that change.

Comment: @ChamalPradeep Yes, i did that, but I'm not happy with it. It works, but it screw with the Separation of concerns principle.

Comment: Yes, That might be happened but it also a better way to achieve relationships in loopback. Otherwise you have to use operational hooks to control scenarios.

Comment: I choose a better way: stop using loopback. I'm tired of fighting with the tool that should make the work easier. It's not the first time i loose days of work trying to understand a problem with loopback. I give up.